# RaphaelJS with rgba gradient fill

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am trying to create a gradient fill with RaphaelJS that uses rgba colors. In other words, I want both the start and end points to have a degree of transparency. For instance, 20% black to 0% black. How is this done?

This fiddle is how I expect that this would be accomplished but as you can see, the bottom black is completely opaque. http://jsfiddle.net/4aPj2/

```
r.circle(50,50,50).attr({fill:'90-rgba(0,0,0,0)-rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',opacity:0})
```

Comment: This is a bug / implementation of Raphael. Also, since VML supports only 2 opacity stops (start and end) this will not reflect on older IE browsers.

Answer (score 7):

Ok,

previous answer is a red herring for anyone looking at this question. I just spent half a day digging around through the raphaeljs source code. It's not this simple. So Raphaeljs actually already has some built in support for this and anything you try to modify like above won't work as the built in support will override it later.
The support that Raphaeljs currently has allows you to set the transparency of the final color-stop using the opacity attribute and the fill-opacity, so for example this:

```
r.circle(50,50,50).attr({fill:'90-#000000-#0000ff',opacity:0})
```

would translate in the real world to a circle with 100% opacity in the first color stop(black) in the center and 0% opacity in the final stop(blue). Another example :

```
r.circle(50,50,50).attr({fill:'90-#000000-#ffffff',opacity:0.5})
```

would produce a real world circle with 100% opacity black in the center and 50% white opacity around the outer of the circle on the final stop.

There is no current way in Raphaeljs to support different opacities on both color stops but if you desperately needed to do this this source line you would need to modify would be here :

```
$(stops[stops.length - 1], {"stop-opacity": value});
```

It's located at 6265 in the current version of Raphaeljs (2.1.0).
I hope this helps someone avoid the hours of debugging RaphealJS source code I just spent....

Comment: Thanks Jeff for updating here. :)

Comment: The above answer has been updated to incorporate the changes that were initially missed. I guess, from the subtlety of the change, red herring seems to be a misplaced vocabulary!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, but that involves editing `raphael.js`

Locate the code block:

```
el.appendChild($("stop", {
    offset: dots[i].offset ? dots[i].offset : i ? "100%" : "0%",
        "stop-color": dots[i].color || "#fff"
}));
```

And replace it using:

```
el.appendChild($("stop", {
    offset: dots[i].offset ? dots[i].offset : i ? "100%" : "0%",
        "stop-color": dots[i].color || "#fff",
        "stop-opacity": R.is(dots[i].opacity, "undefined") ? 1 : dots[i].opacity
}));
```

**Update: Later figured out that I had accidentally missed a one-line change from my patch.**

Next, locate the following line within the function `R._parseDots`

```
par[2] && (dot.offset = par[2] + "%");
```

and replace it with

```
dot.opacity = dot.color.opacity;
par[2] && (dot.offset = par[2] + "%");
```

With the above code, you can easily use something like `myRect.attr("fill", "90-rgba(255,0,0,0.25)-rgba(0,255,0,0.75)-rgba(0,0,255,0.25)");` But note that the solution is for SVG output, VML does not support this. VML only supports a single opacity on gradient at 0% position and optionally a second opacity for the last opacity at 100% position. There would be a few more code changes for VML that I am not including here.

The code can be seen in action in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shamasis/SYdJW/

Comment: Thanks Shamasis. My example only had 2 stops - one on each end - so that shouldn't disqualify it from working in VML, should it? I tried updating the Raphael source as you mentioned and it didnt make any changes. Please see my updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4aPj2/1/

Comment: I tried stepping through the debugger and the `dots` never had the `.opacity`properties. I tried adding `dot.opacity = dot.color.opacity;` to `R._parseDots` just before `dot.color = dot.color.hex;`. Now, both the `<lineargradient>`s are getting rendered with `stop-opacity="0"` regardless of whatever value was in `dots[]`. I'm getting in over my head now so I dont think I'll be able to dig down further at the moment.

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow. It's late night here now.

Comment: @Jeff I have updated the code to also include the section I hadn't mentioned earlier. The change is very minor in one more function. Also, I presume that negative vote can now be removed.:-)

Comment: It wasn't my negative vote, but here's a +1 for follow through :) I'm on a different project now so it may be a while before I swing back around to this.

Comment: @Jeff - Would love to see if this has worked for you. Also, the change has been put in https://github.com/fusioncharts/redraphael - in case you wanna see it. :-)